# Solution for dual security in spring boot application - OAuth2 (jwt token bearer) + X509 (certificates)

Tags: spring-boot, x509, spring-oauth2

I tried to create a spring boot configuration with dual security checks on requests (**Oauth2** token bearer and **X509** certificates). I had 2 alternative ideas in mind, but cannot make it work either

1. dedicated endpoints for each type of security validation (/certif
   for certification validation, /token for token validation)
2. all endpoints checked with either token or certificate validation
   anything successfully would apply

This is my configuration that tries to achieve idea no 1:

```
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${xxx.auth.resourceId}")
    private String resourceId;

    @Autowired
    private DefaultTokenServices tokenServices;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId(resourceId)
                .tokenServices(tokenServices)
                .tokenExtractor(new BearerTokenExtractor());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/unsecured/**")
                .antMatchers("/token/**")
            .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/unsecured/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            ;
     }
}


@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class X509ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
                http.requestMatchers()
                        .antMatchers("/certif/**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/certif/**").hasAuthority("AUTH")
                .and().x509().subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)").userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }



    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsService() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
                if (username.startsWith("xxx") || username.startsWith("XXX")) {
                    return new User(username, "",
                            AuthorityUtils
                                    .commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("AUTH"));
                }
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found!");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

For some reason I cannot make it work because filter `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` seems to be deleting the authorization token created by filter `X509AuthenticationFilter` when I make a call with a certificate to /certif/info. I must mention that `ResourceServerConfiguration` is working ok when used alone and the /token/info endpoint is called with a token.

Mentioned filters are in `spring-security-oauth:2.3.8` & `spring-security-web:5.6.2`
Orders have been changed in every direction but they seem to have no effect on how the filters are applied.
Any idea what is going on and how can I avoid this problem in order to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: use `antMatcher` instead of  `antMatchers` on the cert path side.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to config just one Configuration class.
You can join the two methods named as "configure", in just one.
I didn't test this code, but tell me if you did it working.

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/unsecured/**")
                .antMatchers("/token/**")
                .antMatchers("/certif/**")
            .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/unsecured/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/certif/**").hasAuthority("AUTH")
                .and().x509().subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)").userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
            ;
     }
```

Comment: where is the oauth2 check here? should be optional if there is a certificate available